# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I'm trying populate data in my modal using Faker
but I got the error.
here is my Code

```
import os
from faker import Faker
from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AccessRecord

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')
import django
django.setup()
import random

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top=add_topic()
        fake_url=fakegen.url()
        fake_date=fakegen.date()
        fake_name=fakegen.company()

        webpg=Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec=AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]

if __name__=='__main__':
    print('populating script')
    populate(30)
    print('Completed')
```

I think error is due to this line

> os.environ.setdefault

but when I comment this line it doesn't populate data

Below is the error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJA
>   NGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call `django.setup()` before **importing your models**:

```
import os
import random
from faker import Faker

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')
import django
django.setup()

from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AccessRecord

#...
```

Comment: `import os
from faker import Faker
from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AccessRecord
import django
import random
django.setup()
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')`

Comment: So you didn't change the order? the `from first_app.models import ...` should be **after** those three lines (check the answer again).

Comment: `import django

django.setup()

from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AccessRecord

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')`

**like this?**

Comment: No, the `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')` should be before the `from first_app.models import Topic...`. (Check the order in the answer). Basically, you should let django know about your settings so that it can identify your app and hence, your models.

Answer (score 0):

I got recently a very similar error

```
ERROR project/tests/test_models.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are no...
ERROR project/tests/test_priced_offers.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings...
```

This happened, because I was running pytest in the root folder, not in the project folder. Error disappeared when I executed the tests in project folder.

Hope this is helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I just debug my populate.py file and found that i was importing the models.py before configuring Django so first you need to set environment then you need to setup Django and at last you can import models in populate.py file.

```
from faker import Faker
import random
import django
import os

# Configure settings for project
# Need to run this before calling models from application!
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_model.settings') # this should be done first.

# Import settings
django.setup() # This needs to be done after you set the environ

from first_app.models import Topic, WebPage, AccessRecord # At last you can import models in populate.py file


fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t


def populate(N=5):
    '''
    Create N Entries of Dates Accessed
    '''

    for entry in range(N):

        # Get Topic for Entry
        top = add_topic()

        # Create Fake Data for entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        # Create new Webpage Entry
        webpg = WebPage.objects.get_or_create(
            topic=top, name=fake_name, url=fake_url,)[0]

        # Create Fake Access Record for that page
        # Could add more of these if you wanted...
        accRec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(
            name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating the databases...Please Wait")
    populate(20)
    print('Populating Complete')
```