# how to send data from scrapy data to a django model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, scrapy

Is it possible to create new products using scrapy in django ?

Whenever I run scrapy.py I get the following error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

my app models file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age =  models.IntegerField()
    content =  models.TextField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

scrapy.py file

```
from models import Product

Product.objects.create(name='BMW', age=25, content='cool car')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it's possible, you just to import `django` and configure the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable :

```
import django
import os

# Configure settings for project
# Need to run this before calling models from application!
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_name.settings') # Replace app_name with your application name.

# Import settings
django.setup()

# Import the models now
from app_name.models import Product

# Use the imported model
product = Product.objects.create(...)
```

More infos [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423321/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-installed-apps-b)

Answer (score 1):

For the error you are having above you might be setting up Django incorrectly.

Therefore, this question have two problems to be solved:

1. Django environment not properly setup.
2. Send data to model from a crawled data.

**1. Fix Django Setup issue **

For the first question I advise you to setup Django normally creating a project.... Then, create an app as `python manage.py startapp product_app` ADD the `product_app` into `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'product_app' <----- without this the models.py won't work.
]
```

Then, go to your `models.py` and create the model `Product` for example. Migrate the model into your database.

Alright your first question might be answered.

**2. Add crawled data into a Django model.**

The second part is send data to the `product` table using the `Product` model (the representation of the product table).

The fields you will create will depend on the data you need. Let say, the data I want to store from the crawled data are: `name`, `description`, `price`, `stock` and if it is `available`.

Great, lets create our model:

product_app/

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default =0)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural =  'products'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Since Django accepts dictionaries as objects to be used for queries you can get this crawled data into a dictionary/json for after be pushed into the `Product` table.

Alright, now for your part you will need to somehow get the data as dictionary as similar this and push into the Product table:

```
data = {
    "name":"bmw", 
    "description":"dont waste your money", 
    "price":25000.00, 
    "stock":4, 
    "available":True
    }
```

query example:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 
>>> from product_app.models import Product
>>> 
>>> data = {"name":"bmw", "description":"dont waste your money", "price":25000.00, "stock":4, "available":True,}
>>> 
>>> product = Product(**data)
>>> product.save()
>>> 
>>> product
<Product: bmw>
```

From here you can do whatever you want with the data. Install Django-Rest-Framework and display the data as an REST-API or display the data in a template.

Bear in mind that you can create the queries needed into views.py or wherever you want.

Comment: it is work only on manage.py shell but not from scrap.py

Comment: Obviously! As I mentioned before, you have to "somehow" iterate the data into the dictionary named as "data" from the fetched data you brought. It might need some for loops and other iterations to format the dictionary as such. It is with you because I dont know how the data is displayed when it is fetched.

Comment: I have tried that data you posted in scrap.py I executed it nothing happened 