# django.setup(): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.apps' when DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I am attempting to add entries to a Django Database from an external Python script, but have run into errors when attempting to import my Django Models.
I am using venv for both the database and the individual Python script

I used the following link: [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423321/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-installed-apps-b) to attempt to setup Django before importing my Model, but now I am running into the following error:
***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.apps'***

I also set the Python Path to be at the top of my project directory, which is above both my Database and Python Script.

The Python file I am attempting to create is in a different folder from my Database, and here is the code:
(Note that my Django database name is database, and is the main part as well. I have "api" as a separate directory.)

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.database.database.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from database.api.models import Example
```

This fails on django.setup(). I have done an alternate attempt with "from database.database.wsgi import *" that results in the same Error.

I am unsure of what causes this, as when I run the database, the models in "api" appear just fine, and I do add api to "INSTALLED_APPS".

This is my INSTALLED_APPS inside of my database.settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

"api.apps" is a basic file I have in my project, and I do not do much with it other than the default behavior.

What could still be causing this to have the ModuleNotFoundError for api.apps?

Comment: put down api.apps.ApiConfig

Comment: @sarangkkl Can you clarify where to put down api.apps.ApiConfig? If you mean in the INSTALLED_APPS, it is already there. Or do you mean somewhere in the Python Script?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

sorry for late replay but this is what i am saying you need to put the your created app after the static files remember always python in interpretedd programming language

Comment: if not work it might wrong with your app name so the best thing please share your file heirarchy

Comment: you can reach me directly by sarangkkl@hotmail.com

Comment: Ah, I see! That's good to know for the future. I ended up going another way (Using Django Commands)

Answer (score 0):

This has been an old thread, but just in case somebody facing the same problem and the answer and comment in the above answer is not clear, here is my take:

1. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.apps' error is quite clear that django could not find a module name apis/apps.py
2. The OP solved the issue using Djanggo command:

   **python manage.py startapp apis**

Which then will generate a folder name apis, module apps.py, and all the necessary files.
(I don't know what all generated files called, yet, as I've just found the solution when I am learning to use Python + Django to develop web service)